# How can I figure out why my mini-max tic-tac-toe AI does not work?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I am trying to make a minimax tic-tac-toe game because I am a novice at Python and I am trying to figure out how a simple AI-mini-max game works. The AI for some reason still goes in order in which the spot turns up on the list for the board.

Ex: if the top right spot was first in the "b" list, it picks it first. It looks like it is calculating the scores, but I do not think it is utilizing them for some reason. I want it to not go in order of what the spaces in the board. I can't figure out a way to replace the code that places the "O".

```py
import random
import math

three = [0, 0, 0]
game = True
turnai = False
result = ""
b = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
x = "X"
o = "O"
#Spots on the board Ex: ur = upper right, mm = middle middle, lm = lower middle
ur = b[2]
um = b[1]
ul = b[0]
ml = b[3]
mm = b[4]
mr = b[5]
ll = b[6]
lm = b[7]
lr = b[8]
cw = " "

AI = ""
player = ""

#Board setup
def board(ul, um, ur, ml, mm, mr, ll, lm, lr):
    print("|" + " " + ul + " " + "|" + " " + um + " " + "|" + " " + ur + " " + "|")
    print("|" + " " + ml + " " + "|" + " " + mm + " " + "|" + " " + mr + " " + "|")
    print("|" + " " + ll + " " + "|" + " " + lm + " " + "|" + " " + lr + " " + "|")


board(ul, um, ur, ml, mm, mr, ll, lm, lr)
print("This is the game of tic-tac-toe")
print("You will be playing against an AI")
print("Type where you want to place your letter Ex: ur = upper right, mm = middle middle, and ll = lower right")

first = "P"
player = "X"
AI = "O"

#Checks if someone has won
def checkwinner():
    ur = b[2]
    um = b[1]
    ul = b[0]
    ml = b[3]
    mm = b[4]
    mr = b[5]
    ll = b[6]
    lm = b[7]
    lr = b[8]
    row1 = [ul, ml, ll]
    row2 = [um, mm, lm]
    row3 = [ur, mr, lr]
    column1 = [ul, um, ur]
    column2 = [ml, mm, mr]
    column3 = [ll, lm, lr]
    diagonal1 = [ul, mm, lr]
    diagonal2 = [ur, mm, ll]
    if row1 == ["X", "X", "X"] or row2 == ["X", "X", "X"] or row3 == ["X", "X", "X"] or column1 == ["X", "X",
                                                                                                    "X"] or column2 == [
        "X", "X", "X"] or column3 == ["X", "X", "X"] or diagonal1 == ["X", "X", "X"] or diagonal2 == ["X", "X",
                                                                                                      "X"]:
        if player == x:
            print("You win! (X)")
            return "X"
        if player != x:
            print("You lose!")
            return "O"
    if row1 == ["O", "O", "O"] or row2 == ["O", "O", "O"] or row3 == ["O", "O", "O"] or column1 == ["O", "O",
                                                                                                    "O"] or column2 == [
        "O", "O", "O"] or column3 == ["O", "O", "O"] or diagonal1 == ["O", "O", "O"] or diagonal2 == ["O", "O",
                                                                                                      "O"]:
        if player == o:
            print("You win! (O)")
            return "X"
        if player != o:
            print("You lose")
            return "O"
    if b[0] != " " and b[1] != " " and b[2] != " " and b[3] != " " and b[4] != " " and b[5] != " " and b[
        6] != " " and b[7] != " " and b[8] != " ":
        print("TIE!")
        winner = True
        return "0"
    return "null"
#Minimax Algorithm
def minimax(b, depth, isMaximizing):
            result = checkwinner()
            if result != "null":
                score = scores[result] + score
                return score

            if (isMaximizing):
                bestScore = -math.inf
                j = 0
                for str in b:
                    if str == " ":
                        b[j] = AI
                        score = minimax(b, depth + 1, False) + score
                        b[j] = " "
                        bestScore = max(score, bestScore)
                    j += 1
                return bestScore

            else:
                bestScore = math.inf
                k = 0
                for str in b:
                    if str == " ":
                        b[k] = player
                        score = minimax(b, depth + 1, True) + score
                        b[k] = " "
                        bestScore = min(score, bestScore)
                    k += 1
                return bestScore


#Game Start loop
if (first == "P"):
    while (game == True):
        i = 0
        scores = {
            'O': 1,
            'X': -1,
            '0': 0
        }
#AI turn
        bestScore = -math.inf
        turnai = False
        i = 0
        for str in b:
            if str == " ":
                b[i] = AI
                score = minimax(b, 0, True)
                b[i] = " "
                print(score)
                if score > bestScore and turnai == False:
                    bestScore = score
                    b[i] = AI
                    turnai = True
            i += 1
        turnai = False
        print("")
        # b = [ul, um, ur, ml, mm, mr, ll, lm, lr]
        ur = b[2]
        um = b[1]
        ul = b[0]
        ml = b[3]
        mm = b[4]
        mr = b[5]
        ll = b[6]
        lm = b[7]
        lr = b[8]
#Prints Board
        board(b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5], b[6], b[7], b[8])
        cw = checkwinner()
#Checks if game ended
        if cw == "X" or cw == "O" or cw == "0":
            game = False
            break
#Player turn
        print("Where do you want to place your letter?")
        turn = input(": ")
        if turn == "ur" and ur == " ":
            b[2] = player
            uru = True
        if turn == "um" and um == " ":
            b[1] = player
            umu = True
        if turn == "ul" and ul == " ":
            b[0] = player
            ulu = True
        if turn == "mr" and mr == " ":
            b[5] = player
            mru = True
        if turn == "mm" and mm == " ":
            b[4] = player
            mmu = True
        if turn == "ml" and ml == " ":
            b[3] = player
            mlu = True
        if turn == "lr" and lr == " ":
            b[8] = player
            lru = True
        if turn == "lm" and lm == " ":
            b[7] = player
            lmu = True
        if turn == "ll" and ll == " ":
            b[6] = player
            llu = True
#Prints Board
        board(b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5], b[6], b[7], b[8])
        sw = checkwinner()
#Checks if game needs to be ended
        if cw == "X" or cw == "O" or cw == "0":
            game = False
            break
```

Comment: Try to keep the questions Simple and to One Specific idea at a time. Try to boil down your question to one example that others can run and see your result.  Try to show the result you get and then what you want, that may help others.

Comment: Can you at least narrow down/isolate the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As a general style rule try to keep your line lengths < 100 characters.
- You shouldn't use `str` as a variable name as it is a builtin.
- You can use `enumerate` to get the index and the value from a list as you iterate.
- `scores` should be defined in `minimax` because that's the only place it is used.
- AI is taking the first spot available because of this section of code:

  ```
  bestScore = -math.inf
  turnai = False
  i = 0
  for str in b:
      if str == " ":
          b[i] = AI
          score = minimax(b, 0, True)
          b[i] = " "
          print(score)
          if score > bestScore and turnai == False: # Allways true first loop
              bestScore = score
              b[i] = AI 
              turnai = True                         # ^ Never true in later loops
  ```

  Which ironically only occurs when `turnai == false`
- You don't actually need your `turnai` boolean in game loop because you explicitly code both the ai and user turns.
- You don't need to check if a `boolean == True` just say `while game:`
- You don't need to `break` if your control bool is set to false.
- If the user enters invalid input they lose their turn.
- you have `sw = checkwinner()` then you examine the value of `cw`

I could fix this for you but I think I've given you enough to work with here and I will tell you that your concept is sound(ish) so if you just keep with it a little further you should get some satisfactory results...

The major logical flaw here is that you never actually count how many wins a given choice leaves... Your minimax function just returns 1 every time.

Comment: Would it be better if I did score += scores[result] where score is set at zero at the very beginning?

Comment: Also, how can I make it place the 'O' in the position with the highest score because I see what you are saying, but I have know clue how to select the spot with the highest score.